# jquery is setting a inline style for height when i slideToggle...css3?

Tags: jquery, css, height, shadowbox

Jquery is adding a inline style for height on my `#shadowBox` when i use `slideToggle()`I have no idea why this is happening or how to get rid of it...
[http://test.yamiko.org/cp/](http://test.yamiko.org/cp/#) is the page. The shadowBox is animated when you click login or contact.

```
//login script
$('#header a[title="Sign In"], #login>button').click(function()
{
    if($('#login').is(':visible'))
    {$('#login').slideUp(1000).parent('#shadowBox').delay(1000).fadeToggle(1000);}
    else{$('#shadowBox').fadeToggle(1000).children('#login').delay(1000).slideDown(1000);}
});
```

I have tried 
`$('#shadowBox').height($(document).height());` but it gets overwritten by the inline style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slideDown method allows an optional callback, you could change

```
$('#shadowBox').fadeToggle(1000).children('#login').delay(1000).slideDown(1000);}
```

to

```
$('#shadowBox').fadeToggle(1000).children('#login').delay(1000).slideDown(1000, function() { 
  $('#shadowBox').height("100%"); 
});
```

If you want to remove the height altogether you could change my last example to

```
$('#shadowBox').fadeToggle(1000).children('#login').delay(1000).slideDown(1000, function() { 
  $('#shadowBox').height(""); 
});
```

Comment: doesnt fix the problem the height is the same as the viewport...the problem is jquery is adding the inline style. if i remove it its fine but i dont know why jquery is adding the inline style. http://yamikowebs.com/test/cp/# is the same page with different css and it works fine there with the same js. and jquery doesnt add the inline style there...

Comment: Hmmmm, besides removing the inline style, what is your endgame? Rather than setting the height to 100% in the callback function, you could instead set it to an empty string which will effectively remove it.

Comment: for shadowbox to be height of the whole page.it is a css problem.its height can go over the viewport.Im using new css display elements not sure what exactly is causing it though.

Comment: I am certain my previous examples work, but you can use this code in place of your last example: $('#shadowBox').height($("body").height());

Comment: your solution is working thx. its causing a little lag which is fine...Im still curious what css rule im doing to cause the strange behavior. I think jQuery has trouble with the new display table values and its a bug/not yet implemented into jQuery.

Comment: interestingly `$('#shadowBox').height($("body").height())` doesnt do the thing on its own. that was the first thing i did. it will set the height to the max size of the viewport and has something to do with the new display table values. on another note the code works fine as the call back or when it is part of the chain...even if it is the beginning of the chain. I will submit this as a jquery bug.